# how to rewrite 5*3**n/6 as 5/2*3**(n-1) :I want string ok

Tags: sympy

I want to use sequence

I want string ok

```
5*3**n/6 ---> 5/2*3**(n-1)
```

I try

```
from sympy import *
var('n')
f=5  *3**n/6
g=5/2*3**(n-1)
print("#",f,simplify(f))
print("#",g,simplify(g))
# 5*3**n/6       5*3**n/6
# 2.5*3**(n - 1) 0.833333333333333*3**n
```

(2022-02-11)

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powsimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from sympy import powsimp
>>> powsimp(5*3**n/6)
5*3**(n - 1)/2
```